# Upload a file to database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, image-uploading

I have a mysql database where I want to upload a image with SpringMVC and Thymeleaf. I'm not using Spring boot.

PhotoController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String form() {

        return "form";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/doUp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String subirFoto(@RequestParam("file") File file) {

                byte[] imageData = new byte[(int) file.length()];

                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    fileInputStream.read(imageData);
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Photo image = new Photo();
                image.setNombre("test.jpg");
                image.setFoto(imageData);

                try {
                    photoService.insertPhoto(image);
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return "success";
    }
```

form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<h1>Spring Boot file upload example</h1>


<form th:action="@{/doUp}" th:object="${file}" method="get" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If I change the method and I try to upload the image with

```
File file = new File("/home/Desktop/pokemon.jpg");
```

works ok, but I need to upload the file by a form.

I get the next error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: pokemon.jpg (No existe el archivo o el directorio)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.myproject.controller.PhotoController.subirFoto(PhotoController.java:90)
```

I can understand the problem is with the image's path but I don't know who fix it...

Comment: take a look at this https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: I can't use it because I'm not using spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Spring Content JPA](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/)?  This can provide a storage service and REST endpoints for managing content and, if you want it to, associate that content with JPA entities.

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

> Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class) // enable Spring Content Rest
public class MysqlConfig {

  // Initialize the database schema
  //
  @Value("/org/springframework/content/jpa/schema-drop-mysql.sql")
  private Resource dropReopsitoryTables;

  @Value("/org/springframework/content/jpa/schema-mysql.sql")
  private Resource dataReopsitorySchema;

  @Bean
  DataSourceInitializer datasourceInitializer() {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator =
            new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

    databasePopulator.addScript(dropReopsitoryTables);
    databasePopulator.addScript(dataReopsitorySchema);
    databasePopulator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);

    DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);

    return initializer;
  }
}
```

Create a "store":

> ImagesStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="images")
public interface ImagesStore extends Store<String> {
}
```

This is all you need to create REST endpoints @ `/images`.  When your application starts, Spring Content will look at your dependencies (seeing Spring Content JPA & REST), look at your `ImagesStore` interface and inject an implementation of that interface for JPA.  It will also inject a `@Controller` that forwards http requests to that implementation.  This saves you having to implement any of this yourself which I think is what you are after.

So...

`curl -X POST /images/pokemon.jpg` -F "image=@/home/Desktop/pokemon.jpg"

will store the image in the database (as a BLOB).

`curl /images/pokemon.jpg`

will fetch it again and so on...supports full CRUD.

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  The  reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/jpa-index.html).  And there is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).  The coding bit starts about 1/2 way through.

HTH

Comment: I don't use Spring boot

Comment: No problem.  I updated the answer to use standard Spring enablement.